# Facebook API: Searching for pages created after some date

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, search

I have been using the Graph Search API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0) to fetch Facebook pages that contain certain keywords. Is there a way to limit the search to a date range (i.e. pages that were created after a specific date). I tried using the 'since' keyword, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Search api is deprecated in version2.0 . Check the roadmap https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_graph_api